# ng-grid not able to resize cellTemplate column with specific width

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

```
{
 field: 'community_name',
 displayName: 'Community Name',
 cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><a tooltip="{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}" tooltip-placement="right" ng-cell-text class="override-link">{{row.getProperty(col.field)|truncate}}</a></div>', 
 cellClass: 'cellToolTip',
 width: 150
}
```

I want this column to be resized when dynamically adding more columns to grid. I can not remove the fixed width of 150. It should be there for the first loading of the grid. But when adding more column to the grid, this should be reduced. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can update column width like this:

```
$scope.columnDefs = [
  {
    field: 'id',
    displayName:'Id',
    width: 80
  },
  {
    field:'name', displayName:'Name'
  }
]

$scope.gridOptions = { 
  data: 'myData',
  columnDefs: $scope.columnDefs 
};

$scope.changeColumnWidth = function() {
  $scope.gridOptions.$gridScope.columns[0].width = 300;
}
```

**Example:** [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/DyEj6A?p=preview)